# useSelector of React Redux don't update state of store on expo react-native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, expo, hook

I made the same model on the web and it worked, I tried to use shallowEqual of Redux as second parameter of useSelector function, also the  _.isEqual of lodash libary as there on the Redux documentation in Hooks section but don't worked.

**Expected behavior:**

On dispatch action the components with useSelector must bring the updated state.


**What happens:**

The components brings the initial state empity.

**versions:**

```
"Expo": "~37.0.3"
"react-native": "37.0.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5"
```

EDITED:

I tried to reproduce the structure similar to the snack that also reproduced the same problem, here is the link: https://snack.expo.io/@danieltfischer/useselector

Comment: your state is only updated on handleSubmit. It should be empty unless you call handleSubmit.

Comment: I called handleSubmit function, when I back to Dashboard screen the state keeped empty. Also on the log nothing changed.

Comment: Are you using the state you get from useSelector somewhere, how are you determining that it's not bringing the latest state?

Comment: Danyal, I am. I pass the state as "data" to the FlatList component where it also receives "data" as property. I used the useSelector on the form and on the dashboard and put a log to make sure they would receive the updated status and also as I said I am using the state in a flatList component that was to render the items coming from the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at your code, and I found one bug.

You are not exporting your action type string constant from the `actions` folder:

```js
// What you are doing
const CREATE_MED = 'CREATE_MED';

// What you need to be doing
export const CREATE_MED = 'CREATE_MED';
```

After I fixed this, the app is working, as soon as I dispatch the action it brings back the latest state for me and updates the flatlist too.

Try making this change and see if it fixes it.

The reason it wasn't working is because every time the reducer function is called the `CREATE_MED` action constant is undefined, so it always went to the default options which was returning the previous state.

Comment: I was even ashamed. Thank you very much, it was a silly mistake I didn't realize,

Comment: I'm glad it fixed the bug, try to use `Redux Devtools`, this kind of bugs are easily caught in it. and I think using something like ESLint auto catches these kind of import/export bugs.  You can mark this answer as the solution, thanks. :)

Comment: I had copied eslintrc.json from another project and forgot to activate it at the beginning of the project, silly error... I already added your answer as a solution. Thank you again!